# Fubini's theorem and independent random variables

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, independence, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent random variables. I want a really detailed proof of $\mathbb{E}(X_1 X_2) = \mathbb{E}(X_1)\mathbb{E}(X_2)$ using Fubini's Theorem. So the statement I have of Fubini's theorem is (special case of just two measureable spaces):

> Let $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ be $\sigma$-finite measures on $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{F}_1)$ and $(\Omega_2, \mathcal{F}_2)$. Let $f$ be a Borel function on $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{F}_1)\times (\Omega_2, \mathcal{F}_2)$. Suppose that either $f \geq 0$ or $f$ is integrable with respect to $\nu_1 \times \nu_2$. Then
> $$
> \int_{\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2} f(\omega_1, \omega_2) d(\nu_1 \times \nu_2) = \int_{\Omega_2} \biggl( \int_{\Omega_1} f(\omega_1,\omega_2) d \nu_1 \biggr) d \nu_2
> $$

Now,

$$
\mathbb{E}(X_1 X_2) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} u t \, d P_{X_1,X_2} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \biggl( \int_{\mathbb{R}} ut \, d P_{X_1} \biggr) d P_{X_2}
$$

I know that $P_{X_1,X_2} = P_{X_1} P_{X_2}$ by independence and that $P_{X_1}$ and $P_{X_1}$ are $\sigma$-finite measures on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$. However, I do not really understand why the independence is needed according to Fubini's theorem. Am I confusing $P_{X_1,X_2}$ with $P_{X_1} \times P_{X_2}$? Or does independence give you the $\sigma$-finite condition? Basically, the question is: what does independence buy you in the theorem as stated above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Independence has nothing to do with sigma finiteness. Here all the measures are finite measures.

Fubini's Theorem applies only to product measures. It does not apply to a general measure on a product space. So to apply Fubini's Theorem to find $E(X_1X_2)$ the joint distrbution $P_{X_1,X_2}$ has to be the product of $P_{X_1}$ and $P_{X_2}$ and this condition is equivalent to independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$.